How to get an animated skins on bedrock?
I have seen some skins that change color or looks in the shop, so I tried making a gif to use as a skin, but it says I need to make it a png. How can I have animated skins?

maybe apng works?

yeah, but a PNG would be a still image

a gif is basically a PNG just  ya know... moving

apng is basically a gif but as a png. You can try this tool I found online.

I'm 90% sure the only way to get animated skins on Bedrock is via the marketplace.

Maybe so. I'll have to look up on how they did it soon.

I'm pretty sure you have to become a partner via their partner program
